# SQL DB Design: One project - Many roles

Tags: sql, database, schema, creation

I'm trying to wrap my head around how a DB schema would look like when you have a project like:

```
> +----------------+  +----------+  
| Project          |  | roles    |  
+------------------+  +----------+  
| project_id       +  + role_id  +
| project_roles_id +  + role_name+
+------------------+  +----------+
```

So my issue is trying to figure out how to add multiple roles to a project. If a project has a capture manager, a project manager and a proposal manager... how do I best create that within a schema?

Comment: Actually, the issue is `not enough information`.

Comment: You need a table called something like `ProjectRoles`, with one row per `project` and one row per `role` on that project.

Comment: I believe you are asking about `many-to-many` relationship.  If this is the case, the solution is usually to use a 3rd table (`Project_Role` in your case).

Comment: Would I have to define all the possible roles? I was envisioning being able to have users add multiple roles to a project depending on what type of project it is. Some projects may only have two roles, some may have 3 or 4.

Comment: Designing a database is one thing.  Data entry is something else altogether.  How much data gets entered by the designer is up to the business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
::: projects :::
+------------+---------------------+
| project_id | project_name        |
+------------+---------------------+
| 1          | Scoping a project   |
+------------+---------------------+
| 2          | Building a bridge   |
+------------+---------------------+
| 3          | Building a SQL db   |
+------------+---------------------+

::: roles ::: 
+---------+-------------------+
| role_id | role_name         |
+---------+-------------------+
| 1       | Project Manager   |
+---------+-------------------+
| 2       | Civil Engineer    |
+---------+-------------------+
| 3       | Computer Engineer |
+---------+-------------------+

::: roles_to_projects :::
+------------+---------+
| project_id | role_id |
+------------+---------+
| 1          | 1       |
+------------+---------+
| 2          | 1       |
+------------+---------+
| 2          | 2       |
+------------+---------+
| 3          | 3       |
+------------+---------+
```

This tells you (with minimal duplication) which roles are required for which projects.

Comment: with Project_id and role_id being PK's and the roles_to_projects would both be FK? Or would project Id still be a PK there?

Comment: You're correct - the IDs are PKs in their normal tables (projects, roles) and FKs in the many-to-many mapping table (roles_to_projects).